# dbContext estático com Entity Framework: Compensa ou não?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Galera, utilizo Entity Framework e Code First para gerenciar meu acesso a dados, e estou pensando em trabalhar com uma única instancia, estática e global de meu DataBaseContext. Porém tenho duas questões:

1. Quais problemas poderiam ocorrer com esse tipo de uso?
2. Existe algum Padrão de Projeto de exemplo para isso?

Segue exemplo de como acesso os dados em meu banco:

**ATUALMENTE** - Cada método chama uma instancia do *BaseDados*

```
using (var db = new BaseDados())
{
    var fatura = db.Contas_Receber.Where(x => x.Chave == chaveFatura).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**POSTERIORMENTE** - Existirá apenas uma instancia do *BaseDados*, e todos os DAOs do meu sistema utilizarão esta instancia.

```
public static class DAO<T> where T : class
{
    private static SETCOM_BaseDados db;

    public static void Create(T entidade)
    {
        db.GetInstance();

        try
        {
            db.Set<T>().Add(entidade);
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entidade, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao inserir dados : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public static class BaseDadosExtension
{ 
    public static SETCOM_BaseDados GetInstance(this BaseDados db)
    {
        return (db == null ? new BaseDados() : db);
    }
}
```

Chamada para criar um novo *Contas_Receber*:

```
Contas_Receber cr = new Contas_Receber();
cr.Valor = 0;
cr.Cliente = new Cliente();

DAO<Contas_Receber>.Create(cr);
```

Comment: (Possível) Problema 1: Vai deixar o contexto sempre "aberto" (sem dispose)?

Comment: Problema 2: O tratamento da exceção tá horrível, jogar o stacktrace fora e dar atenção pra mensagem é uma das piores coisas que você pode fazer com uma exceção.

Comment: Não vale a pena, o `EF` tem como base o `UoW`. Da forma como está fazendo, este único contexto vai começar a rastrear toda e qual quer entidade que for consultada, desta forma, a cada operação irá ficar mais lento e consumindo mais memoria, eventualmente a sua aplicação vai morrer.

Comment: @LINQ poderia me dar um exemplo de como tratar de forma correta? Tenho uma extensão criada para Exception aqui chamada "GetAllMessages" e utilizo ela para pegar o StackTrace completo, esse try catch é apenas para este exemplo

Comment: @RenanValentim Deixar ela estourar é muito melhor do que ignorá-la e criar uma nova com a mensagem da original.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita então o correto é sempre instanciar o DBContext em cada método?

Comment: @RenanValentim se não tiver nada à fazer, como fechar uma conexão, estornar uma operação, liberar um recursos, etc... então não precisa tratar, deixe a Exception fluir e trate ela apenas no seu tratamento de exceção global.